# Electron Error: write EPIPE at afterWriteDispatched

Tags: node.js, .net, electron, electron.net, epipe

After building our Electron app on Mac we see a popup coming with below error, same app is working on windows without any error.
Note: App keeps running but this error popup comes 4-5 time

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: write EPIPE
at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:917:11)
at Socket._write (node:net:929:8)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:300:16)
at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:377:26)
at Server. (Contents/Resources/app.asar/main.js:166:13)
```

When i see the error line in js it is console.log
do we require to give any extra permission in mac?

Comment: Currently as a workaround we removed console.log from main.js and its started working